# No entiendo por que este codigo con switch statement no da error de conpilacion ni un excepcion en Runtime

Tags: java, switch

```java
   int param1 = 1;
        switch (param1){
            case 0:
                int block2 = 10; // si se comenta esta linea error de compilacion
                System.out.println(block2);
                break;
            case 1:
                block2 = 5; // si se comenta esta linea lo de abajo es un error de compilacion
                System.out.println(block2);
                break;
            default:
//                System.out.println(block2); // error de compilacion
        }
```

Intente hacer debug y no tiene sentido por que no veo donde es declarada la variable. este codigo corre en un main

Comment: Que error te salta?? De donde sale la variable block2?

Comment: Hola Alan, si comentas **int block2 = 10;** la variable **block2** nunca fue declarada, error, si comentas **block2 = 5;** nunca fue instanciada, de ahí los errores recibidos.

Comment: Lo extranho es que se declara e instancia en case 0 pero mi param es 1 entonces va a case 1 y alli no es declarada solo es instanciada

Comment: Siempre que contestes un comentario, pon **@nombreDeUsuario** para que este sea notificado, el "**scope**" (ambito de vida de la variable), está delimitado por las llaves, toda declaración dentro de el, es tomada por el sistema, ahora, yo no lo haría así, hubiese declarado **block2** fuera del switch, creo que es más "limpio".

Comment: @MarcePuente Gracias, esta como ejemplo en un libro para la certificacion de Java de las cosas validas en Java (pueden no seguir las buenas practicas), es mas claro y entendible de la forma que decis

Comment: Me alegra haberte ayudado!!!

Answer (score 0):

[Pregunta respondida en Inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10810847/22259978)

**Traduzco:**

Las declaraciones switch son extrañas en términos de alcance, básicamente. Fuente [sección 6.3 del JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3):

> El alcance de una declaración de variable local en un bloque (§14.4) es el resto del bloque en el que aparece la declaración, comenzando con su propio inicializador e incluyendo cualquier otro declarador a la derecha en la declaración de variable local.

En su caso, 'case 2' está en el mismo *bloque* que 'case 1' y aparece después de él, aunque 'case 1' nunca se ejecutará... Por lo tanto, la variable local está en el ámbito y disponible para *escribir* a pesar de que lógicamente nunca "ejecuta" la declaración. (Una declaración no es realmente "ejecutable", aunque la inicialización sí lo es).

Si comenta la asignación 'block2 = 5;', el compilador aún sabe a qué variable se refiere, pero no habrá pasado por ninguna ruta de ejecución que le asigne un valor, por lo que obtiene un error como lo haría cuando intenta leer cualquier otra variable local no asignada definitivamente.

Le recomiendo encarecidamente que **no** use variables locales declaradas en otros casos, ya que conduce a un código muy confuso, como ha visto. Cuando introduzco variables locales en sentencias switch (lo que trato de hacer raramente, los casos deberían ser muy cortos, idealmente) generalmente prefiero introducir un nuevo alcance:

```
case 1: {
    int value = 1;
    ...
    break;
}
case 2: {
    int value = 2;
    ...
    break;
}
```